# Not able to Expand PSObject

Tags: powershell

I am pulling information from a database with the DNS name of a system. Once I get the information, I have it set up to replace the the parts of the the computer name that I no longer want.

The problem is, however, that once the replacement is performed, I can no longer select the objects - it just returns blanks if you select `DnsName` or if you look at the variable it will just show `@{Dnsname=computer123}`. I have tried `-ExpandProperty`, but that doesn't work either.

```
function ExecuteSqlQuery($SQLQuery) {
  $Server = "localhost"
  $Database = "DB123" 
  $Array = @() 

  #Create and open a database connection
  $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
  $Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;"
  $Connection.Open()

  #Create a command object
  $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
  $Command.Connection = $Connection
  $Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery

  #Execute the Command
  $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
  $Counter = $Reader.FieldCount

  #Parse the records
  while ($Reader.Read()) {
    for ($i =0; $i -lt $Counter; $i++) {
      $Array += $Reader.GetValue($i)
    }
  }

  # Close the database connection
  $Connection.Close()
  return $Array
}

$DNSsys = "SELECT DnsName FROM Systems"
$DNSName = ExecuteSqlQuery ($DNSsys)

$DNSName = $DNSName -replace '.123.com', '' -replace '.abc.com', ''
```

I also ran into the same issue when I pull information from SCCM with the code below, where everything is fine until `-replace` is run:

```
# Create the PSSession
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName sccmserver

# Load the CM Module using Implicit Remoting
Import-Module -Name "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1" -PSSession $Session

#Set the CMSite as our current location to run the CM cmdlets
Invoke-Command -Session $Session {Set-Location -Path LOC:}

$SCCMdevices = Get-CMDevice -CollectionName "All Systems" | Where {$_.IsActive -like "True"} | Select-Object -Property Name, DeviceOS

$SCCMdevices = $SCCMdevices -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 5.1', 'Windows XP' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 5.1 (Tablet Edition)', 'Windows XP' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.1', 'Windows 7' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.1 (Tablet Edition)', 'Windows 7' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.1 (Embedded)', 'Windows 7' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.2', 'Windows 8' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.2 (Tablet Edition)', 'Windows 8' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.3', 'Windows 8.1' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 6.3 (Tablet Edition)', 'Windows 8.1' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 10.0', 'Windows 10' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 10.0 (Tablet Edition)', 'Windows 10' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Server 5.2', 'Windows Server 2003' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Advanced Server 5.2', 'Windows Server 2003' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.0', 'Windows Server 2008' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Advanced Server 6.0', 'Windows Server 2008' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.1', 'Windows Server 2008 R2' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Advanced Server 6.1', 'Windows Server 2008 R2' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.2', 'Windows Server 2012' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Advanced Server 6.2', 'Windows Server 2012' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Server 6.3', 'Windows Server 2012 R2' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Advanced Server 6.3', 'Windows Server 2012 R2' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Server 10.0', 'Windows Server 2016' `
                        -replace 'Microsoft Windows NT Advanced Server 10.0', 'Windows Server 2016' `
                        -replace '6.1', 'Windows 7' `
                        -replace '10.0', 'Windows 10'
```

Comment: The function you posted should return an array of strings for the given query, not an array of objects.

Comment: Please consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Adding another code snippet that does something entirely different is not going to help clarify your question. Besides, instead of using a metric ton of `-replace` operations I'd strongly recommend mapping OS names to their replacement value with a hashtable in the second script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way to approach it so you're not running the string modifier -Replace against the entire object, but rather just that property:

`$Array += $Reader.GetValue($i) | Select-Object *,@{N="HostName";E={$_.DNSName -replace '.123.com', '' -replace '.abc.com', ''}}`